# Find the lowest / highest key of a distributed map

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have a distributed map and I want to find the lowest or highest key (an object implementing compareable). What is the most efficient way to get those keys? I mean something like every node provides his lowest key and in the end the lowest key is the lowest of every node.

So I think:

```
MyObj max = Collections.max(map.keySet());
```

is not the most efficient way. And if I want to use

```
new DistributedTask<>(new Max(input), key);
```

I would need to now the key and therefore fetch all Keys over wire. I think in that case I could do Collections.max(map.keySet()); as well.

Hmm ... any ideas?

Comment: map.keySet is extremely inefficient and dangerous to use. It will suck in the whole keyset of the map into the memory of a single JVM. There is no batching going on, so you can easily get an OOME because of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This map reduce solution seems to have a lot of overhead but it is the best way I could get the job done. Any better ideas are still welcome.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    IMap<String, Integer> map = instance.getMap("test");
    JobTracker jobTracker = instance.getJobTracker( "default" );
    KeyValueSource<String, Integer> source = KeyValueSource.fromMap( map );
    Job<String, Integer> job = jobTracker.newJob(source);

    JobCompletableFuture<Map<String, String>> future = job
            .mapper(new MaxMapper())
            .reducer(new MaxReducerFactory())
            .submit();

    System.out.println("mr max: " + future.get());
}


public static class MaxMapper implements Mapper<String, Integer, String, String> {
    private volatile String max = null;

    @Override
    public void map(String s, Integer integer, Context<String, String> ctx) {
        if (max == null || s.compareTo(max)>0) {
            max = s;
            ctx.emit("max", max);
        }
    }
}

public static class MaxReducerFactory implements ReducerFactory<String,String,String> {

    @Override
    public Reducer<String, String> newReducer(String s) {
        return new MaxReducer();
    }

    private class MaxReducer extends Reducer<String, String> {
        private volatile String max = null;

        @Override
        public void reduce(String s) {
            if (max == null || s.compareTo(max)>0) max = s;
        }

        @Override
        public String finalizeReduce() {
            return max; // == null ? "" : max;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also add a Combiner to lower the traffic drastically since for every chunk of data emitted from Combiners you would just give the current min and max. I'll add a full example below.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`EntryProcessor.executeOnEntries`](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/entryprocessor.html) - with a stateful [`EntryProcessor`](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/map/EntryProcessor.html) - and then let the it do all the work for you; have each key map to a sentinel `MIN` and `MAX` enum if they are the min and max.

If you have some idea of the bounds, you could attach a filter [`Predicate`](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/query/Predicates.html) as well to speed it up that way, too.

Comment: "Hazelcast sends the entry processor to each cluster member and these members apply it to map entries. So, if you add more members, your processing is completed faster.". Are you sure that the very same object is passed around? Otherwise I will just get the lowest key of the local node.

Comment: I can't easily test this. However, I would try it, and if you get multiple results, just calculate the min and max of the results returned from the local clusters. It should still be faster than `Collections.max`, as you don't have to pull ALL the elements.

Comment: Hmm this seems not to work very well and to get all the keys from the nodes I would need a queue or another distributed map. I think it is a bit of an overhead but I will use a Mapper and Reducer.

Answer (score 0):

Mapper:

```
import com.hazelcast.mapreduce.Context;
import com.hazelcast.mapreduce.Mapper;
import stock.Stock;

public class MinMaxMapper implements Mapper<String, Stock, String, Double> {

    static final String MIN = "min";
    static final String MAX = "max";

    @Override
    public void map(String key, Stock value, Context<String, Double> context) {
        context.emit(MIN, value.getPrice());
        context.emit(MAX, value.getPrice());
    }
}
```

Combiner:

```
import com.hazelcast.mapreduce.Combiner;
import com.hazelcast.mapreduce.CombinerFactory;

public class MinMaxCombinerFactory implements CombinerFactory<String, Double, Double> {

    @Override
    public Combiner<Double, Double> newCombiner(String key) {
        return new MinMaxCombiner(MinMaxMapper.MAX.equals(key) ? true : false);
    }

    private static class MinMaxCombiner extends Combiner<Double, Double> {

        private final boolean maxCombiner;

        private double value;

        private MinMaxCombiner(boolean maxCombiner) {
            this.maxCombiner = maxCombiner;
            this.value = maxCombiner ? -Double.MAX_VALUE : Double.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        @Override
        public void combine(Double value) {
            if (maxCombiner) {
                this.value = Math.max(value, this.value);
            } else {
                this.value = Math.min(value, this.value);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Double finalizeChunk() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public void reset() {
            this.value = maxCombiner ? -Double.MAX_VALUE : Double.MAX_VALUE;
        }
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
import com.hazelcast.mapreduce.Reducer;
import com.hazelcast.mapreduce.ReducerFactory;

public class MinMaxReducerFactory implements ReducerFactory<String, Double, Double> {

    @Override
    public Reducer<Double, Double> newReducer(String key) {
        return new MinMaxReducer(MinMaxMapper.MAX.equals(key) ? true : false);
    }

    private static class MinMaxReducer extends Reducer<Double, Double> {

        private final boolean maxReducer;

        private volatile double value;

        private MinMaxReducer(boolean maxReducer) {
            this.maxReducer = maxReducer;
            this.value = maxReducer ? -Double.MAX_VALUE : Double.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        @Override
        public void reduce(Double value) {
            if (maxReducer) {
                this.value = Math.max(value, this.value);
            } else {
                this.value = Math.min(value, this.value);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Double finalizeReduce() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Returns two elements map with min and max:

```
ICompletableFuture<Map<String, Double>> future =
        job.mapper(new MinMaxMapper())
        .combiner(new MinMaxCombinerFactory())
        .reducer(new MinMaxReducerFactory())
        .submit();

Map<String, Double> result = future.get();
```

Comment: this gives me the key of the max value in the map, I really need the max key. But thanks, I think I can modify this to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an ordered index? Although I'm not quite sure if it currently is possible to find a maximum value using a predicate and once found, abort the evaluation of the predicate.